# открыты к сотрудничеству или для сотрудничества?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какой из вариантов верен:открыты к сотрудничеству или для сотрудничества? или оба?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сказать: открыты (= доступны) для сотрудничества или готовы к сотрудничеству.

Примеры

Мы всегда готовы к сотрудничеству.

В частности, наша академическая система на юге России открыта для сотрудничества.